# VS Code Document Symbol Provider Incremental Refresh

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to implement a document symbol provider for a VS Code plugin I'm working on.  It's partially implemented, and this is invoked when I open a document.  What I can't get to work is to refresh after the document has changed.

Is there a way to either manually trigger this to refresh, or to change the behavior so that it will automatically refresh when the file is saved or changed?

```
export class DocumentSymbolProvider implements vscode.DocumentSymbolProvider {
  public async provideDocumentSymbols(document: vscode.TextDocument, token: vscode.CancellationToken): Promise<vscode.SymbolInformation[]> {
    ....
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?